# wso2 Configuring a keystore

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

i'm trying to add new keystore to Wso2 IS using following Link

[link to create new key](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS521/Creating+New+Keystores#CreatingNewKeystores-Relatedlinks)

also this link for key configuration

[https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=43991187

when i finished all configuration, i tried to run the server but get  **"localhost took too long to respond."**

i tried to check the logs i found the following error :

**LifeCycleException while starting tomcat connector**

you can find the log file with this link :

[wso2carbon.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TedzZU62l-uMC26OS4D-3rIn4WplUiV0)

Comment: Did you configure new keystore details in configuration files?

Comment: Did you read your logs? "java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Comment: Yes , i following configration in link i added up

Comment: @gusto2 i saw the error and i checked the password nothing incorrect

Comment: Looks like there is an error in one of your user store files.
File name is required to be the user store domain name(eg.: wso2.com-->wso2_com.xml).